# Assign each extracted comment to a single row write.table R data frame

Tags: r, write.table

first of all I am a coding noob and just started coding for the purpose to write my master's thesis at my university. I extracted youtube comments using the tuber package in R in order to carry out a sentiment analysis of those comments. Everything worked fine and I received a data frame with all the comments (11314 observations and 13 variables). However, when i tried to write a .csv file of that data frame in order to look at the comments in Excel I encountered a particular issue. For the comments that contain new paragraphs, the write.table function created a new row. I used the following function:

```
write.table(testneuohneduplikate, file = "Testneuohnedulikate.csv",sep = ";", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE, quote = TRUE)
```

Is there a possibility that each comment is written in a single row and not sometimes two or three rows because the comment contains paragraphs?

I hope I was able to explain my problem properly.

Thank you guys in advance and greetings from Germany to wherever you are from :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, write.table is creating a new row when it encounters a newline character. Here's an example of stripping out newline characters out of the comment string:

```
> comment<-"I think this video \n is great"
> cat(comment)
I think this video 
 is great

> fixedcomment<-gsub("[\r\n]", "", comment)
> cat(fixedcomment)
I think this video  is great
>
```

you can use 'apply' to apply it to every column in your table, or modify the MARGIN parameter if you only want to do rows or columns.

```
> ID<-1:4
> Names<-c('name1','name2','name3','name4')
> Comments<-c("I think this video \n is great", "No it stinks \n I mean it", "Use the Force", "It's time \n to get to work")
> table<-cbind(ID, Names, Comments)

> fixed_table<-apply(X=table,MARGIN=c(1,2),FUN = function(y) gsub("[\r\n]","",y))
```

Comment: thank you very much for that information! Could you also help me to implement that into the function i posted above?

write.table(testneuohneduplikate, file = "Testneuohnedulikate.csv",sep = ";", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE, quote = TRUE)

Comment: This is a common problem, and some of the quickest solutions are depending on your OS (i.e. Windows vs OsX).  For instance, in Windows, you could export your df not a csv but as a tsv -tab separeted values. Excel and OpenOffice in windows are much better handling TSV than CSV. 
Yet, why don't you post a reproducible example? Select a few observations from you data frame and export them with dput() and paste the resulting code into your question.

Comment: OK, I edited the answer to show how to apply this to a dataframe.  If you need further refinement, read up on the APPLY function.